# Generating Heat Maps with GeoHash

Tags: qgis, heat-map, geohash

I have a long list of GeoHash codes for a certain geographic region. I'm using 6-character precision so for example if the area under study was Earl's Court in London, I would have a few six letter codes that for that region.

What I want to do is to be able to generate heat maps using this information. Specifically I want to colour a set of codes based on a certain condition.

I have searched but the only thing I have seen is the GeoHash query page (http://geohash.org/c216ne), but that just returns a marker to the a specific position, *not the area*.

Are there any tools for generating a heat map with this geoHash Information?

Comment: Are you hoping to generate a continuous values [heat map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) (like temperatures based on weather-station readings; [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map#mediaviewer/File:WOA09_sea-surf_SAL_AYool.png)) generated from the points in your GeoHash file, or are you trying to create a [choropleth map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) of polygons that would be associated with areas the points are in?

Comment: I'm looking at a choropleth., and that's  exactly what I want to do except with squares. The idea is, I have an excel spreadsheet that looks something like this [{ccstsr, 45},{ccstsq, 77},{ccbvty, 10}]. Let's say ccstsr and ccstsq are in the same township so i'll call both Wembley. Then I want to plot the population of these towns that I have redefined from the geohash codes, on a map where each town is highlighted by the areas covered by all its associated codes.(that's two geohash codes for Wembley and 1 for the other town)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

I created a simple python script for converting geohashes to 3d Google Earth representations.  This isn't exactly what you asked for, but if you'd like to create a cool looking thematic map (based on geohash) this will get you started.

You can get the code on github here:

[geohash2kml](https://github.com/abeusher/geohash2kml)